# MySQL to CSV using PHP and replacing values

Tags: php, mysql, csv

help needed. When a column value of the column customer_id='0', I need to replace it with the value 'Guest'. Here is my code, I have tried everything I could find without success. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//Connection to database
mysql_connect("localhost","Username","Password");
mysql_select_db("DB_Name");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT

`order`. order_id,
`order`. customer_id,
`order`. payment_company,
`order`. payment_address_1,
`order`. payment_address_2,
`order`. payment_city,
`order`. payment_zone,
`order`. payment_postcode,
`order`. payment_firstname,
`order`. payment_lastname,
`order`. telephone,
`order`. email

FROM `order`
INNER JOIN customer ON `order`.customer_id = customer.customer_id
WHERE order_status_id > 0 ORDER BY order_id");
if (!$result) die('Sorry, I was unable to any fetch records. Try again');
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

$headers = array();

// Creating headers for output files
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
{
    $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
}

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result)
{
// name of file with date
    $filename = "Filename-".date('Y-m-d').".csv";

        // Setting header types for csv file.
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header('Expires: 0');
        fputcsv($fp, $headers);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
             fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
        }
        die;
 }
?>
```

Comment: Just a side note: you don't need to write `\`order\`.` in front of every field if you're only selecting from `order` anyway.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: So if `customer_id = '0'` you want `customer_id` to be set to "Guest", is that correct?

Comment: Hi Matt, yeah. If customer_id="0" then replace the zero with the word 'Guest' and include it with the csv output.

Comment: Thanks Guy's. All of the answers do not enter additional rows into the csv file when the customer is a 'Guest'. Is it being wiped out by the "INNER JOIN customer ON `order`.customer_id = customer.customer_id" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT order.order_id,
       CASE WHEN order.customer_id = '0' THEN 'Guest' ELSE order.customer_id END AS customer_id, 
...
```

Comment: Thanks! To make this work I had to remove the INNER JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $row[1] = (($row[1]  == '0') ? 'Guest' : 0);
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to just hack in before the fputcsv

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        if($row[1] == '0') {
            $row[1] = 'Guest';
        }
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
```

Also look into while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  that wat you can use $row['customer_id'] instead of $row[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
`order`.order_id,
IF (`order`.customer_id = 0, 'Guest', `order`.customer_id) AS customer_id,
`order`.payment_company,
etc..");
```